# Remove the suffix `^M` when run ls in org src

Tags: org-babel, microsoft-windows, line-endings

When run `ls` to print the file list

```
#+begin_src ipython :session sql :results output
! ls | head -n 5


#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: create.txt^M
: Lesson 10. Grouping Data.md^M
: Lesson 11. Working with Subqueries.md^M
: Lesson 12. Joining Tables.md^M
: Lesson 13. Creating Advanced Joins.md^M
```

There are always `^M` characters appended,

My machine info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux alpha 5.3.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 01:33:18 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How can I disable such a line-ending representation?

My machine is " Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 19.10 Release: 19.10 Codename: eoan "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those Control-M characters (`^M`) are no doubt end-of-line chars used by your OS - probably MS Windows.

(Please provide your OS/platform in the question.  And if it's Windows then state how you are using OS command `ls` - e.g., Cygwin, `ls-lisp.el`, or something else.)

You can control this `^M` display using the buffer coding for line endings.  Something like this might be all you need:

```lisp
(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system (coding-system-change-eol-conversion
                                         (default-value 'buffer-file-coding-system)
                                         'unix))
```

But for more information, see these nodes in the Emacs manual:

- [Coding Systems](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Coding-Systems.html)
- [Recognize Coding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recognize-Coding.html)
- [Mode Line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mode-Line.html)

Comment: My machine is "
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:        19.10
Codename:       eoan
"

Comment: Please put all such info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.